# Set of constants that I can iterate through

Tags: java, android

I often run into a situation where I need to define a set of constants and I need to loop through them. Lets say  Card Suit where I need to display the list of available suits to the user.

The two options I see are enums or static int. But the thing is that when I need to iterate through the list, I end up using enum with values() and Ordinal(). Many people say using these are bad and you should go back to static int.

How do you guys code a set of constants where you need you iterate through them? What's the best practice?

Thanks

Comment: Enum and values(). IDK why that wouldn't be the proper way to do it... I can't think of any downsides to that method.

Comment: "Many people say using these are bad" -- FWIW, few Java and Android experts agree with that advice, and feel that enums are perfectly fine (at least in moderation). See [Jake Wharton](https://twitter.com/JakeWharton/status/638447874515275776), [Bob Lee](https://twitter.com/crazybob/status/636959556539539457), and [Joshua Bloch](https://twitter.com/joshbloch/status/628663950389841920), for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's okay to use the `values()` method. In fact, the [Java tutorial for enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) mentions this explicitly:

> The compiler automatically adds some special methods when it creates an enum. For example, they have a static `values` method that returns an array containing all of the values of the enum in the order they are declared. This method is commonly used in combination with the for-each construct to iterate over the values of an enum type. For example, this code from the Planet class example below iterates over all the planets in the solar system.

```
for (Planet p : Planet.values()) {
    System.out.printf("Your weight on %s is %f%n",
                  p, p.surfaceWeight(mass));
}
```

Enums provide some advantages over constant ints, such as stronger type-checking. But if you absolutely had to code-tune, and were certain that you were not optimizing prematurely, you could use constant ints and an array containing them. *Disclaimer: I'm not recommending this for usual practice. Please don't do this by default.*

```
private static final int SUIT_SPADES = 1;
private static final int SUIT_CLUBS = 2;
private static final int SUIT_HEARTS = 4;
private static final int SUIT_DIAMONDS = 8;

private static final int[] SUITS = new int[] { 
   SUIT_SPADES, SUIT_CLUBS, SUIT_HEARTS, SUIT_DIAMONDS };

...
for ( int suit : SUITS ) { ... }
```